# why am I getting these warnings when running a bootstrap test in R

Tags: r, bootstrap

After I run a boostrap method in R I get the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In boot.ci(res) : bootstrap variances needed for studentized intervals
2: In norm.inter(t, adj.alpha) :
  extreme order statistics used as endpoints
```

I'm just trying to understand why I get these as warnings. I'm running an ordinary nonparametric bootstrap.

My code is below:

```
sqrt_sum_of_squares <- function(data,indices){
    k<-data[indices,]
    return(sqrt(sum(k^2)))
  }
#bootstrap step
  d <- c(4583,3285,3382,3920,4822)
  d <- as.data.frame(d)
  results <- boot(d, sqrt_sum_of_squares, 1000)
```

Comment: While R stuff is *often* off-topic, I think this particular question has enough statistical content to be-topic for CrossValidated, so I voted to keep this open.

Answer (score 3):

The studentized confidence interval [(bootstrap-t page 126)](http://www.researchgate.net/publictopics.PublicPostFileLoader.html?id=547fcfbcd4c11815398b4836&key=7223d3be-e577-4597-9ed1-d94debfda8d9) is created by using the bootstrap samples to estimate a t-statistic. The confidence interval is defined as

$$
\Big[\hat{\theta} - Q_{(1-\alpha/2)}(t^*_i) s.e.(\hat{\theta}),\hat{\theta} - Q_{(\alpha/2)}(t^*_i) s.e.(\hat{\theta})\Big]\\
t^*_i = \frac{\hat{\theta^*_i}-\hat{\theta}}{s.e.(\hat{\theta^*_i})}
$$

$\hat{\theta}$ is the sample estimate, $\hat{\theta^*_i}$ are the bootstrap estimates, and $Q_{(1-\alpha/2)}(t^*_i)$ are the quantiles from the bootstrapped $t^*_i$ estimates.

For studentized confidence intervals to work, the statistic function needs to return the statistic and also the estimated variance. The R help `?boot` has an example of the returning the variance of the difference of two means. *Note:* The second parameter of diff.means() is frequencies not indices.

For your statistic, I'm unsure how to compute the variance. It is possible to [bootstrap the bootstrap](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2007spring/biol/145/001/docs/lectures/Sep17.html) in this case, though it gets quite slow. It would be something like

```
sqrt_sum_of_squares_helper <- function(data,indices){
    k<-data[indices,]
    return(sqrt(sum(k^2)))
}

sqrt_sum_of_squares <- function(data,indices){
    k<-data[indices,]
    b <- boot(as.data.frame(k), sqrt_sum_of_squares_helper, 100)
    return(c(sqrt(sum(k^2)), var(b$t)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!